# How many Gayatri Chalisa/Mantra Janevdhari Brahman has to do?

Tags: gayatri-mantra, yagnopavitam, gayatri

I heard that After taking Janev Brahman has to do some number of Gayatri Mantra to praise Mother Gayatri in lifetime. It is curse due to Janev. Is it so? If yes, how many Gayatri Mantra malas brahman has to do?

Comment: It is not a curse! You should chant Gayatri 108 times in the morning and 64 times in the evening, if possible 32 times in the afternoon.

Comment: Janev giving is called yagyopavitra sanskar in Hindu culture. Once the batuk(The person taking Janev) agrees to do 24 thousand Malas in his lifetime, he is given Gayatri mantra as Diksha. Diksha means tenacity in being righteous for chanting mantra in lifetime. 1 Mala= 108 mantras
24,000 Mala = 24,000*108 = 2,592,000 Mantras A brahman has to do at least 2,592,000, if he has taken janev. But a brahman can do any number greater than 2,592,000 in his lifetime.

Comment: The question is related to Diksha or yagyapavitra sanskar.